# Add/remove items management with Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a Shiny App and I would like my user to choose from a list of items contained in a vector such as below:

```
vec <- c("Tokyo", "Newyork", "Paris", "London", "New Delhi", "Sydney")
```

I would like to use a concept similar to the picture below. [image]

Is there any existing control widgets in Shiny to do this? I am open to an alternative solution but keep in mind that my list contains in reality 100 cities and I want to stay user-friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `selectInput` to achieve something like this. It's not exactly the same, but achieves the same result

```
library(shiny)

vec <- c("Tokyo", "Newyork", "Paris", "London", "New Delhi", "Sydney")
ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel(""),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("city", "Select city", vec, multiple = TRUE)
      ),

      mainPanel(
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```